# Listing migrations shows no migrations found, why?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I've got an ASP.NET project that uses Entity Framework 7 RC1. I'm trying to use migrations to create my database. I've create an initial migration, and see the generated code in my project. Immedietly after creating the migration, I run the `dnx ef migrations list` command, but it says that no migrations were found. Also, if I try to apply the migration it does not look like it creates the tables that are inside of the generated migration code - it does create a database, though.

Any ideas?

Comment: So you get an empty database, no tables? Not used ef7 yet; does it still have the dbo.__migrationhistory table, and if so, what's in it?

Comment: Right, I get an empty database, no tables. It does have the migration history table, but the table has no rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just in case the link goes away.  The github issue that Ryan links to says to add .MigrationsAssembly("[project]") after the call to UseSqlServer.  Something like this.

```
services.AddEntityFramework()
.AddSqlServer()
.AddDbContext<ExampleContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]).
    MigrationsAssembly("Example.Api"));
```

or now even better you can use --targetProject per

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Design-Meeting-Notes-(October-28,-2015)

```
cd src\MyApp
dnx ef migrations add MyMigration --targetProject MyApp.Data
```

This will add the Migrations to the TragetProject where the DbContext lives

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that the issue has to do with my project structure. My `DbContext` is defined in one project, while my migrations were being created in my other project. This does not seem to work out of the box, but how to make this work is detailed here :https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3840

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem.

```
dnx ef migrations list
```

showed empty list. Then I realized that I moved part of my "db classes" to another project.
Solution how to do it properly is here:
http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/moving-entity-framework-7-models-to-external-project
thx Jerrie ;)

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue. For me options.MigrationsAssembly("Example.Api") was part of the solution. Because I was doing integration unit testing that recreated the database using a injected custom mock DbContext, still no migrations were returned. This was caused by the fact that the migrations where linked to the original DbContext in the database/infrastructure layer, and not to my mock DbContext in the unit tests.

Please make sure that the following conditions are met for migrations to work correctly;

1. The migrations are linked to the same DbContext that you are using to actually provision the migrations
2. The Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational NuGet package is included and at exactly the same version as the other EfCore NuGet packages
3. Specify the assembly that contains the migrations using options.MigrationsAssembly("Example.Api")